# Capacitor in AC circuit

Tags: electric-circuits, capacitance

Can someone explain to me the process of discharging of a capacitor when the EMF of AC source is decreasing? And where do charges go? I mean if there's a weak battery, it will be charged but what about AC source?

Answer (score 2):

When you apply an AC voltage to a capacitor, current will flow into the capacitor, and back out again. As long as the absolute voltage on the AC generator is higher than on the capacitor, current will flow to increase the charge on the capacitor; and when it's smaller, current will flow to decrease the charge.

Note that since there is an equal and opposite amount of charge on the capacitor, there is no "net" charge flow - if more positive charge flows onto one plate, an equal amount leaves the other plate.